# Omit/delete second bar under the navigation bar in szeged theme?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

The code below gives nice slides with a navigation bar on top that leads to the different sections (I have no subsections) in the presentation. However, below the navigation bar there is a second bar (grey) without any content that I would like to get rid off because it just takes up space. Does anyone know how to do that? Removing that bar would result in the "perfect" presentation for me.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usetheme{Szeged}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}

\title[Short title]{\textsc{{Long title 1}}}   
\author{Aut Hor} 
\institute[Short Ins]{Ins}
\date{\today} 

%***********************************
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage} 
\frame{\frametitle{Outline}{\tableofcontents}}


\section{FIRST SECTION}
\frame{\frametitle{FIRST FRAME} 
\begin{itemize}
    \item item 1 
    \item item 2
\end{itemize}
}

\section{SECOND SECTION}
\frame{\frametitle{SECOND FRAME} 
\begin{itemize}
    \item item 4
    \item item 5
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 10):

As lockstep explained, the `Szeged` theme does:

1. applies `compress` option
2. loads `miniframes` outer theme with theme options `footline=instituteline` and `subsection=true`
3. sets a `separation line` color which is suppressed with `\usecolortheme{Seagull}`.

Knowing that you can just apply `compress` option and change options for `miniframes`  with next preamble:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
...
\useoutertheme[subsection=false, footline=institutetitle]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{Seagull}
```

[Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42957/1952) provides a better solution:
`Szeged` theme loads `miniframes` outer theme with `subsection=true` which clashes with a later call to `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}`. This clash is avoided if `subsection=false` option is set before loading themes:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{subsection=false}{beamerouterthememiniframes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Szeged} % implicitely loads miniframes
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\frame{Hello} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a superior method. Sadly, `beamer` doesn't seem to allow first loading a "complete" theme like `Szeged` and only then disabling some of its underlying options.

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, it seems so. In any case, Stefan Kottwitz provides a better solution [in my following question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42957/1952).

Comment: I tried all of those solutions and they all work. Thank you very much! One final question. Is it possible to get rid of the thin white line (probably it is only white in seagull color scheme) that separates the navigation bar from the top border of the slide?

Comment: If this white line first appears on second frame, it's a compatibility problem between older versions of pgf and beamer. Update both packages and the line will disappear.

Comment: Thank you Ignasi. I discovered that the white line only appears in Sumatrapdf not in Adobe reader.. so problem solved..

Answer (score 8):

The `Szeged` theme uses the `miniframes` outer theme which declares the `beamer@theme@subsection` conditional and sets it to `true`. This in turn adds color boxes to display the `\subsection`s. You may remove the boxes by adding the following after `\usetheme{Szeged}`:

```
\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse
\makeatother
```