# Why can't I load miniframes outer theme after Szeged theme?

Tags: beamer, option-clash, mini-frames

Making some tests to answer [omit delete second bar under the navigation bar in szeged theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/omit-delete-second-bar-under-the-navigation-bar-in-szeged-theme) I found that

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\begin{document}
\frame{Hello} 
\end{document}
```

finishes with
`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package beamerouterthememiniframes.` and I would like to understand why is it.

`Szeged` already load `miniframes` with another option but I thought that was always possible to load other themes in order to combine them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could pass the option explicitely to the package, which you could do even before `\documentclass`. Note, we use the full theme package name here:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{subsection=false}{beamerouterthememiniframes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Szeged} % implicitely loads miniframes
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\frame{Hello} 
\end{document}
```

Szeged loads `miniframes` just with a footline option:

```
\useoutertheme[footline=institutetitle]{miniframes}
```

This way, `miniframes` will work also with your option and will not show the subsection line in the header.

Comment: This way, there is no need for explicit `\useotertheme{miniframes}` because is already included with `Szeged`. But, do you know why the clash error?

Comment: @Ignasi: right, I removed the line loading it again. I think the clash occurs because `miniframes` itself sets the option to true if it is not set.